# Need to utilize multiple arrays and have them display out to one dialog box

Tags: foreach

I've posted something earlier about this and didn't get too far and after re doing most of my code maybe it will be a bit easier to see where I am trying to go...

Its still partially done, I am having compiler errors when I am trying to assign the number of values that correlate with "numberOfTaxpayers" into the new arrays created for userGross, userTax, and userNumChild. It compiled with the userfName and userlName strings so any guidance to the right path?

what I have to do is create arrays for each of those categories then have them display all the inputs at the end. So there should be a JOptionPane showing for example:

First Name: Example FName

Last Name: Example LName

Gross Income: example income

Number of children: example number

Tax Due: amount of tax due

and it has to do this for as many users as you enter but output all of them in one box!
not looking for completed code, just some guidance as to where I failed!! (Array lists cannot be used)

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 

class AssignmentSeven
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
```

Comment: `" I am having compiler errors when..."` -- if you're having compiler errors and need help, then comment the lines that are causing the errors with an obvious comment, i.e., `// **** ERROR HERE ****` and post the actual error text here with your question. Else, you're forcing us to guess what it might be, which isn't quite fair to us.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels my apologies; I will make the edit, the compiler error occurring says: cannot find symbol "numberOfTaxPayers" userGross = new double[numberOfTaxPayers] and does the same for the 2 other similar array declarations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CaPiTALiZaTiOn MatTeRs! That's your issue.

```
numberOfTaxPayers != numberOfTaxpayers
```

But the key lesson to get from this is to not ignore the error message as it will often tell you **exactly** what is wrong. Here it's telling you that it can't recognize the `numberOfTaxPayers` variable, and if you look closely at the variable, you'll see that it makes sense, because a variable of exactly that name and capitalization was never declared.

Comment: @prodo. If its any consolation, just this morning I spent a couple of minutes staring at a miscapitalized variable.  Its a good time to go get a coffee and come back with a fresh mind.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels of course... the most simplest of errors get overlooked, embarrassing on my part lol